# Changing preg_match condition

Tags: php, function, preg-match

My function is changing `$word_one` (je/que je in j'/que j'), if `$word_two` begins with a vowel.

```
function FrenchCompoundTenses($word_one, $word_two) {
if(preg_match('~(.*)\bje$~ui', $word_one, $m) && preg_match('~^[aeéiou]~ui>', $word_two)) 
    return "<td class=\"text-right text-muted\">{$m[1]}j'</td>" . $word_two;               
else 
    return "<td class=\"text-right text-muted\">". $word_one ."</td>" . $word_two;
}
```

For a similar function I have to change this part:

`&& preg_match('~^[aeéiou]~ui>', $word_two)`

It should worked, if `$word_two` begin with HTML code `<u>` or `</td><td>`  and then a vowel is following.(`[aeéiou]`)

EDIT: `$word_one` comes from an array with pronoun and `$word_two` comes from a 2-dimensional array. `$word_two` are in this case two words.

example:

```
 $word_one= 'je' +   $word_two='aime'  =  j'aime 
 $word_one= 'tu' +   $word_two='aimes' = tu aimes
```

desired output with this function:

```
 $word_one= 'je' +   $word_two='<u>aime' = j'aime (with html code between)
 $word_one= 'je' +   $word_two='</td><td>aime' = j'aime (with html code between)
```

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't clear at all, and it is difficult to provide a good answer if you doesn't explain what you are trying to accomplish more globally. Why do you need to create this function? From where comes `$word_one` and `$word_two`? Why a variable called `$word...` can contain other things than a single word? Could you show an example of your original datas and the expected result?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have editing my question. After some changing I have to add a new function for changing the pronoun from  `$word_one`. I am searching for someone, who has some time to help me to improve my conjugation script, but this is very hard.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't explain from where comes the html content.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte HTML content is part of the array value (here is it added by an other function).

Comment: I know that html content is part of the array value! The question is why do you have html in this array? Please show your original raw datas.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I can send you the copy of the complete file in pastebin.com in a chat. I don't unterstand, how I can help you else to unterstand the question. I want to underline some letters or put $word_two in two table cells, thats why I use HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&& preg_match('~^h?(?:[aæàâeéèêëiîïoôœuûù]|y(?![aæàâeéèêëiîïoôœuûù]))~ui', strip_tags($word_two))` should solve the problem.

*(I added an optional `h` at the begining since `h` is a silent `h` in french.    I added too several accented vowels)* and the `y` when not followed by another vowel.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It was so easy ... `strip_tags( )` was the answer auf my other question here, but I don't  come up with the idea of using it for this problem. It is right to add  the letter `h` , but `y`  isn't correct. You may  meant `ÿ` . I have add some other french vowels.

Comment: @Grischa: indeed, when the `y` is followed by a vowel like in `yodiser` or `yoyoter` *(`je yodise, je yoyote`)*, but it isn't the case when `y` is followed by a consonant like in `hybrider` or `hypothéquer` *(`j'hybride, j'hypothéque`)*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. Now I understand, why the h isn't in the square bracket ;-). I can't find an easy translation for characters like here `?`,`~ui`. I  am only  know `^` stands for begin of a line.

Comment: @Grischa: `?` is a quantifier and means zero or one, so `h?` zero or one `h` (in other word, the `h` is optional). `~` are the pattern delimiters. `u` and `i` are options: `u` the string must be read as an utf8 string (and it extends the meaning of character class like `\w` or `\d` to the unicode table), `i` means `case-insensitive`.